# Can we ignore a specific S100 warning with SonarLint

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

In our C# project we are using SonarQube/SonarLint.

We have a property called `DMSCode`. `DMS` is an abbreviation we use in our organization, so really is valid. Yet SonarLint is throwing an S100 warning.

Is there a way to ignore this for this code:

```
public string DMSCode { get; set; }
```

I tried searching 'sonarlint s100 ignore' and some other variations, but found nothing.

Comment: Are you using the connected mode?

Comment: Yes. I am using connected mode.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to do it this way:

```
#pragma warning disable S100
    public string DMSCode { get; set; }
#pragma warning restore S100
```

Not sure if this is the best solution, but it works here.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to mark the issue as false positive in SonarQube rather than using the suppress message.

Comment: Even if i does that in SonarQube, next run it's still display same message.